# When to use low < high or low + 1 < high for loop invariant

Tags: algorithm, binary-search, loop-invariant

I've read multiple articles including Jon Bentleys chapter on binary search.  This is what I understand about CORRECT binary search logic and it works in the simple tests I did:

```
binarysearch (arr, low, high, k)
    1. while (low < high)
        2. mid  = low + (high - low)/2
        3. if (arr[mid] == k)
               return mid
        4. if (arr[mid] < k )
               high = mid -1
        5. else 
               low = mid + 1
```

Now to find the 1st occurence with sorted duplicates, you'd chance line 3 if condition to continue
instead of returning mid as

```
binarysearch_get_first_occur_with_duplicates (arr, low, high, k)
    1. while (low < high)
        2. mid  = low + (high - low)/2
        3. if (arr[mid] == k)
               high = mid - 1
               low_so_far = arr[mid]
        4. if (arr[mid] < k )
               high = mid -1
        5. else 
               low = mid + 1
        return low_so_far
```

Similarly to get highest index of repeated element, you'd do `low = mid + 1` and continue if `arr[mid]==k`

This logic seems to be working but in multiple places I see the loop invariant as

```
while (low + 1 < high)
```

I am confused and want to understand when you might want to use `low + 1 < high` instead
of `low < high`.

In the logic I described above `low + 1 < high` condition leads to errors if you test with simple example.

Can someone clarify why and when we might want to use `low + 1 < high` in the while loop instead of `low < high`?

Comment: At a guess, if your invariant is that the target must lie in `low <= i <= high`, then you use `while (low < high)`; if your invariant is that the target must lie in `low <= i < high` then you use `while (low + 1 < high)`.  Having said that, I haven't checked it!

Comment: @Rafe Your guess is correct. Go ahead and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your invariant is that the target must lie in `low <= i <= high`, then you use `while (low < high)`; if your invariant is that the target must lie in `low <= i < high` then you use `while (low + 1 < high)`. [Thanks to David Eisenstat for confirming this.]