# When to use lo <= hi vs. lo < hi for binary search?

Tags: binary-search

While binary search is a pretty algorithm, I've often found myself struggling with "off-by-1" issues for certain applications of binary search.

I have seen variants of binary search where it looks like one of the following 2:

```
while(lo <= hi)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

or

```
while(lo < hi)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

My impression has always been that you can use either, but the body of the `while` loop may change depending on which you use. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: This might help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179225/when-to-use-low-high-or-low-1-high-for-loop-invariant

Answer (score 0):

A simple c# program to show the difference between '<' and '<=':

```
   byte a = 2;

            for(byte b=1; b<4; b++)
            {
                if (a < b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is less then {b}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is not less then {b}");
                }
                if (a <= b)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is less or equal to {b}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{a} is not less or equal to {b}");
                }
            }
```

output:

```
2 is not less then 1
2 is not less or equal to 1
2 is not less then 2
2 is less or equal to 2
2 is less then 3
2 is less or equal to 3
```

Comment: What does this have to do with my question? I'm asking about the usage of each in the context of binary search.

Comment: If this has nothing to do with the question, then please add more info to your question or, ignore this because i did not understand your question.